# What is the difference b/w two sed commands below?

Tags: regex, unix, sed, ksh, aix

Information about the environment I am working in:

```
$ uname -a  
AIX prd231 1 6 00C6B1F74C00  
$ oslevel -s  
6100-03-10-1119
```

---

**Code Block A**

```
( grep schdCycCleanup $DCCS_LOG_FILE | sed 's/[~]/ \
/g' | grep 'Move(s) Exist for cycle' | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' ) > cycleA.txt
```

---

**Code Block B**

```
( grep schdCycCleanup $DCCS_LOG_FILE | sed 's/[~]/ \n/g' | grep 'Move(s) Exist for cycle' | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' ) > cycleB.txt
```

I have two code blocks(shown above) that make use of sed to trim the input down to 6 digits but one command is behaving differently than I expected.

**Sample of input for the two code blocks**

```
Mar 25 14:06:16 prd231 ajbtux[33423660]: 20160325140616:~schd_cem_svr:1:0:SCHD-MSG-MOVEEXISTCYCLE:200705008:AUDIT:~schdCycCleanup - /apps/dccs/ajbtux/source/SCHD/schd_cycle_cleanup.c - line 341~ SCHD_CYCLE_CLEANUP - Move(s) Exist for cycle 389210~
```

I get the following output when the sample input above goes through the two code blocks.

**cycleA.txt content**

```
389210
```

**cycleB.txt content**

```
25140616231334236602016032514061610200705008341389210
```

I understand that my last piped sed command (sed 's/[^0-9]*//g') is deleting all characters other than numbers so I omitted it from the block codes and placed the output in two additional files. I get the following output.

**cycleA1.txt content**

```
 SCHD_CYCLE_CLEANUP - Move(s) Exist for cycle 389210
```

**cycleB1.txt content**

```
Mar 25 15:27:58 prd231 ajbtux[33423660]: 20160325152758: nschd_cem_svr:1:0:SCHD-MSG-MOVEEXISTCYCLE:200705008:AUDIT: nschdCycCleanup - /apps/dccs/ajbtux/source/SCHD/schd_cycle_cleanup.c - line 341 n SCHD_CYCLE_CLEANUP - Move(s) Exist for cycle 389210 n
```

---

I can see that the first code block is removing every thing other that (SCHD_CYCLE_CLEANUP - Move(s) Exist for cycle 389210) and is using the tilde but the second code block is just replacing the tildes with the character n. I can also see that it is necessary in the first code block for a line break after this(sed 's/[~]/ ) and that is why I though having \n would simulate a line break but that is not the case. I think my different output results are because of the way regular expressions are being used. I have tried to look into regular expressions and searched about them on stackoverflow but did not obtain what I was looking for. Could someone explain how I can achieve the same result from code block B as code block A without having part of my code be on a second line?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What version of `sed` are you using? I have version 4.2.1 and I get the same results with both `sed` expressions.

Comment: Can you reformat the example input and output using code formatting instead of quote formatting to ensure that newlines/etc. are displayed correctly?

Comment: It's a good question, but it's buried in noise. Please consider creating an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hello lurker, I tried sed -V and -version but didn't get anything so instead i looked for the version of my unix box: `uname -a AIX prd231 1 6 00C6B1F74C00` and `oslevel -s 6100-03-10-1119`

Comment: Hello Etan, done and done.

Comment: Hello mklement0, is my question lacking in all aspects of MCVE or is there one of those aspects I can improve upon? You can probably tell but I'm new at this and haven't programmed in quite some time. But the itch to program has started and I want to learn while programming.

Comment: (You need to `@`-prefix usernames for users to be notified of your responses.) If you had juxtaposed only the two `sed` commands - one with an actual line break, and the other with `\n` - and had used literal sample input such as `<<<'a~b'`, you would have satisfied the _minimal_ aspect, and demonstrated the problem much more simply. Also note that the _replacement string_ in a `sed` `s/<regex>/<replacement>/` command is NOT a _regular expression_ itself.

Comment: @mklement0 thank you, I will take note for queries in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Etan Reisner's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36228469/45375) explains the problem and offers a single-line solution based on an [ANSI C-quoted string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) (`$'...'`), which is appropriate, given that you *originally* tagged your question [bash](/questions/tagged/bash).
<sup>([Ed Morton's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36235588/45375) shows you how to *bypass* your problem altogether with a *different approach* that is both simpler and more efficient.)</sup>

However, it sounds like your shell is actually something different - presumably `ksh88`, an older version of the Korn shell that is the default `sh` on AIX 6.1 - in which such strings are *not* supported<sup>[1]</sup>
 (ANSI C-quoted strings were introduced in `ksh93`, and are also supported not only in `bash`, but in `zsh` as well).

Thus, you have the following **options**:

- **With your current shell, you must stick with a *two-line* solution** that contains an (`\`-escaped) *actual* newline, as in your code block A.

  - Note that `$(printf '\n')` to create a newline does *not* work, because command substitutions invariably trim all trailing newlines, resulting in the *empty* string in this case.
- **Use a more modern shell** that supports ANSI C-quoted strings, and use Etan's answer. http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.cmds3/ksh.htm tells me that `ksh93` *is* available as an alternative shell on AIX 6.1, as `/usr/bin/ksh93`.
- **If feasible: install *GNU* `sed`**, which natively understands escape sequences such as `\n` in replacement strings.

---

<sup>[1] As for what actually happens when you try `echo 'foo~bar~baz' | sed $'s/[~]/\\\n/g'` in a POSIX-like shell that does *not* support `$'...'`: the `$` is left as-is, because what follow is not a valid variable name, and `sed` ends up seeing literal `$s/[~]/\\\n/g`, where the `$` is interpreted as a context address applying to the *last* input line - which doesn't make a difference here, because there is only *1* line. `\\` is interpreted as plain `\`, and `\n` as plain `n`, effectively replacing `~` instances with *literal* `\n` sequences.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the response. I do happen to have ksh93 like you stated in the directory /usr/bin/ksh93. If I wanted to test out Etan's answer in the script would changing the first line in my script from #!/bin/ksh to #!/bin/ksh93 suffice?

Comment: @ManaFive: Use `#!/usr/bin/ksh93` to be safe, i.e., the _full path_ to the binary (there are platforms, e.g. Fedora, where `/bin` is a symlink to `/usr/bin`, but that's not generally the case). An alternative is to use `#!/usr/bin/env ksh93` which lets the standard `env` utility find the binary in the `$PATH` (even though in this case it happens to be in the same dir. as `env` itself.)

Answer (score 5):

This is an example of the XY problem (http://xyproblem.info/). You're asking for help to implement something that is the wrong solution to your problem. Why are you changing `~`s to newlines, etc when all you need given your posted sample input and expected output is:

```
$ sed -n 's/.*schdCycCleanup.* \([0-9]*\).*/\1/p' file
389210
```

or:

```
$ awk -F'[ ~]' '/schdCycCleanup/{print $(NF-1)}' file
389210
```

If that's not all you need then please edit your question to clarify your requirements for **WHAT** you are trying to do (as opposed to HOW you are trying to do it) as your current approach is just wrong.

Comment: Hello Ed, I really did want to know why code block B did not produce the same results as code block A. All of you were able to enlighten me with the fact that '\n' cannot be used as a new line in my current shell. I am grateful to all of you that invested their time and I gained a better understanding because of it.

Comment: @ManaFive the answer to THAT question had nothing to do with your shell, it's that `\n` is non-portable across sed versions and the version of sed you are running doesn't support it.

Answer (score 2):

GNU sed handles `\n` in the replacement the way you expect.

OS X (and presumably BSD) sed does not. It treats it as a normal escaped character and just unescapes it to `n`. (Though I don't see this in the manual anywhere at the moment.)

You can use `$''` quoting to use `\n` as a literal newline if you want though.

```
echo 'foo~bar~baz' | sed $'s/[~]/\\\n/g'
```

Comment: ++; BSD/OS X `sed` stays close to the POSIX spec. (the only extensions mentioned are `-E`, `-a`, and `-i`), and the [POSIX spec.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) actually declares the interpretation of `\n` in the replacement string _unspecified_ (because `n` is a character that doesn't need escaping). In practice, I can confirm that recent versions of FreeBSD/PC-BSD/OS X interpret `\n` as plain `n`.

Comment: Hello Etan, I ran your example on the unix box and had the following output `echo 'foo~bar~baz' | sed $'s/[~]/\\\n/g' foo\nbar\nbaz` The tildes were replace by \n

Comment: @ProudAtheist The `$'..'` thing is a bash-ism I believe. You are running ksh, not bash, so.... Interesting choice of user name by the way - nothing like yelling your religion at everyone to make for a pleasant environment.

Comment: @EdMorton thank you for the response. Sorry for the offensive user name, I made my user name when I was younger. I have updated it to what I use nowadays.

Comment: @EdMorton: The Korn shell was the first to introduce `$'...'` quoting, namely  in `ksh93` (whereas the OP's default shell is likely `ksh88`); it was later adopted by `bash` (v2) and also `zsh` (v3.1).